# #1215 - Cannot add foreign key constraint ERROR even though the columns are exactly the same

Tags: mysql, foreign-key

Last night I ran `SQL` commands in `phpMyAdmin` **very** similar to the following to setup a `players` table and a `games` table linked by a `foreign key`.  It worked without errors, making `google_id` in my `games` table a `foreign key`.

```
CREATE TABLE players(
    google_id VARCHAR(36) PRIMARY KEY,
    display_name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    given_name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    family_name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    picture_url VARCHAR(2083) NOT NULL,
    leaderboard_initials VARCHAR(40),
    operating_system VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    modified TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
);

CREATE TABLE games(
    game_id VARCHAR(255) PRIMARY KEY,
    google_id VARCHAR(36) NOT NULL,
    won INT(1) NOT NULL,
    score INT(10) NOT NULL,
    num_in_code INT(2) NOT NULL,
    num_colours INT(2) NOT NULL,
    num_guesses INT(2) NOT NULL,
    turn INT(2) NOT NULL,
    rank INT(10) NOT NULL,
    modified TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
);
```

-- Then make the google_id a foreign key in games:

```
ALTER TABLE
    games ADD FOREIGN KEY(google_id) REFERENCES role(google_id);
```

Today the third command gave the following error:

```
Error
SQL query:


ALTER TABLE
games ADD FOREIGN KEY(google_id) REFERENCES role(google_id)
MySQL said: 

#1215 - Cannot add foreign key constraint
```

[AFAIK my `google_id` is exactly the same data type so this answer hasn't helped me](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16969116/1390035)

I've also read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16969176/1390035) but can't see anything wrong with my three queries.

Can anybody spot my mistake?

**EDIT:** Sorry people, this was a typo.  `role` should have been `players`

Comment: Let's see `SHOW CREATE TABLE role`.

Comment: @RickJames mmm.  When I run that I get `#1146 - Table 'idybrand_supercrack.role' doesn't exist`

Comment: Then correct this typo:  `... REFERENCES role(google_id);`

Comment: @RickJames Damn!  Thank you.  Sorry to waste your time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If games table is referring google_id from the parent table "players",then use below syntax (unless you are establishing Foreign key with "role" table as per your SQL statement):

```
ALTER TABLE
games ADD FOREIGN KEY(google_id) REFERENCES players(google_id);
```

Also, please check the DDL of role table(if exists)- datatype, width of column google_id and the mysql engine for both the tables.